# Fundamental Matrix for ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations

Let $x'=\begin{bmatrix}2&-5\\4&-2\end{bmatrix}x$ and $x(0) =\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix} $

I am trying to find the fundamental matrix to this system.

Question 1: I believe that I can find this in 2 ways. One way is $e^At$ and the other is eigenvalues and eigenvectors. They will be complex. Second way is what i am having rouble with.

I believe the eigenvalue is $+4i$ and $-4i$ and the vector equation for the positive value is

$(2-4i)x_1 -5x_2 = 0$

$4x_1 -(2-4i)x_2 =0$

is this correct? I am having trouble solving these two equations. would apreciate some help

PS could someone please explain the method for gettint to the exponential of this matrix also?

Comment: i dont understand how you use RREF in the eigenvector system, in my one, each column has an i coefficient in one of the rows so in the left side, i cant get rid of the $i$ term, could you please advise?

Comment: oh can you subtract $i$ times one row from the other? i guess that is legal actually

Comment: thanks @Moo, i dont know why, but i just didnt really accept that you can add and subtract i times a row to another, i understand this now, cheers mate

Comment: absolutely, cheers ma

Comment: I’m a bit puzzled: how do you propose finding $e^{At}$ if not by computing at least the eigenvalues of $A$?